# What happened to the derelict spaceship after the events of Aliens?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

What happened to the derelict spaceship? Did it survive the explosion of the terraforming processors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your canon may vary.**

In the [Alien: Resurrection novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_Resurrection_(novel)), we learn that the reactor explosion ***entirely vaporised*** the derelict ship.

> It was too bad they didn’t have more historical information. Gediman
> considered it a scientific tragedy that they couldn’t go back to
> planet LV-426, where the Aliens were originally discovered by the
> Nostromo crew. The wealth of information that must have been there!
> But the derelict ship with its bizarre cargo of thousands of eggs had
> been destroyed when the nuclear reactor of a damaged atmospheric
> processor had exploded, leaving nothing behind but radioactive waste
> and a crater nineteen megahectares in size. LV-426 would never be
> habitable again.

---

As seen in *[Aliens: Colonial Marines](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Aliens:_Colonial_Marines_(2013_video_game))*, however, the derelict ship (codename: Origin) survived the explosion of the base at Hadley's Hope ***entirely unscathed*** because it was sitting behind a mountain.

> **Joshua Morris:** *"Quick status update on the derelict ship codenamed Origin. Interior is stable — cross-referencing the ship's current state with reports supplied by y'all, it looks like the Origin has been relatively untouched since the, what was it... USCSS Nostromo encountered it fifty-odd years ago. Hell, even most of the eggs are still intact. If I cared, I'd tell you suits that you're a bunch of exploitative dumbasses who are going to get yourselves, and a lot of innocent people killed. But since my shuttle leaves tomorrow and this little project has got me enough money to buy a small country, I'll just say: Good luck with all of that."*

Comment: I would like to know if it survived the explosion, because if it did, then it is probable that it can still be flown, after destroying all the eggs inside of it of course. Perhaps human engineers can reverse engineer it and make space ships very similar to it.

Comment: @user255577 - All signs point to it having survived. It's not in flyable condition though.

Comment: @ Valorum okay, I'll take your word on it that it's not in flyable condition.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *Alien Resurrection* novelisation it was destroyed when the Hadley AP exploded. The Weyland-Yutani Report said it wasn't a viable source of eggs post-explosion.

It also popped up in *Aliens: Infestation* (completely intact), the *Earth War* comics, the first *AvP* PC game, *Alien Trilogy* game, and other things I've probably missed.